# Why am I not able to use .innerHTML property in this If Statement?

Tags: javascript, if-statement

```html
<button class="js-button" onclick="
    let buttonElement = document.querySelector('.js-button').innerHTML;

    if (buttonElement === 'Subscribe') {
      buttonElement = 'Subscribed';
    } else {
      buttonElement = 'Subscribe';
    }
  ">Subscribe</button>
```

When we click on the button, it should change to 'Subscribed' from 'Subscribe' and vice versa.

When I am saving `.innerHTML` along with the button in the variable `buttonElement`, the If statement doesn't work properly. But, when I use the `.innerHTML` inside the If statement (ex. if (buttonElement.innerHTML === 'Subscribe') and I am not saving innerHTML inside the variable, the If Statement starts working properly. Can you please let me know what could be the reason.

Comment: The `if` statement works properly. You are just assigning to a variable. You should assign to `innerHTML` or `textContent` or `innerText`...

Comment: But also: [do not use the `onclick` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/Event_handlers#registering_event_handlers). Put your JS in its own file, load that script with `<script src="yourfile.js" async defer></script>` and make your JS find the button on your page (lots of ways to do that), so it can call `addEventListener` for it.

Answer (score 1):

You can.  And indeed you are.  The code just isn't doing anything that you are *observing*.  For example, replace those assignment statements with an `alert()` and you can observe that it works:

```html
<button class="js-button" onclick="
    let buttonElement = document.querySelector('.js-button').innerHTML;

    if (buttonElement === 'Subscribe') {
      alert('Subscribed');
    } else {
      alert('Subscribe');
    }
  ">Subscribe</button>
```

Perhaps you meant to do something other than assign a value to a variable?  For example, if you wanted to set the `innerHTML` of the element, you can do that:

```html
<button class="js-button" onclick="
    let buttonElement = document.querySelector('.js-button');

    if (buttonElement.innerHTML === 'Subscribe') {
      buttonElement.innerHTML = 'Subscribed';
    } else {
      buttonElement.innerHTML = 'Subscribe';
    }
  ">Subscribe</button>
```

---

As an aside, you'll find that stuffing a lot of JavaScript code into an `onclick` attribute gets messy *fast*.  Instead, attach it as a click handler:

```js
let buttonElement = document.querySelector('.js-button');

document.querySelector('.js-button').addEventListener('click', function () {
  if (buttonElement.innerHTML === 'Subscribe') {
    buttonElement.innerHTML = 'Subscribed';
  } else {
    buttonElement.innerHTML = 'Subscribe';
  }
});
```

```html
<button class="js-button">Subscribe</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

`buttonElement` is a string and is unlinked from the `innerHTML` so when you change the string then nothing happens. In fact you don't need that variable inside the online function.
See example.

```html
<button class="js-button" 
onclick="
    if (this.innerHTML === 'Subscribe') {
      this.innerHTML = 'Subscribed';
    } else {
      this.innerHTML = 'Subscribe';
    }
  ">Subscribe</button>
```